# What adjustment to this page will solve Blogger's failure to detect the RSS feed?

Tags: blogger

What adjustment to the page http://www.chrisjj.com/tango/cjjsets/ will solve Blogger's "Blog List" gadget's failure (below) to detect the RSS feed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acctually blogger program can't 'read' feed page like (http://www.chrisjj.com/tango/cjjsets/) . But blogger Feed widget can read RSS format like xml. it's look this site have register third party feed XML feed. You can try paste this link (http://feed43.com/chris_milonga_dj_setblog.xml) to Blogger Feed Widget . Tested, it's working. Because Blogger Feed Widget can read it

Comment: Thanks. That works: http://i.imgur.com/DyITDMT.png -> http://i.imgur.com/mUoUIgT.png . Other note: Preview doesn't work: http://i.imgur.com/5Rm3hm4.png

Answer (score -2):

This could be number of reasons but I would start by using the browser console tools and also making sure that the rss service is even running on the remote site.